# Upload xcappdata to device from command line

Tags: ios, xcode5

I can install and run an app on a physical iOS device from the command line using the instruments tool, and run a suite of UI automation tests on the device. I can also create a scheme in Xcode which will install and run an app whilst automatically uploading a .xcappdata file to the device and setting up application state.

I'm trying to find a way to combine these two, and install and run an app on a physical device with a specific .xcappdata file from the command line. I'm hoping that a UI Automation test can be run from a shell script using specific app data to replicate a bug and prevent regressions. Preferably without having to rerun xcodebuild with a new scheme for each xcappdata file.

I've spent a while looking and can't find one, so I've filed a bug report requesting the feature be added to the instruments command (rdar://15955912). In the meantime I'm looking for some kind of workaround to make it happen. Does anyone know of any way of doing this?